# How do i get the ViewModel from Vue's :is

Tags: vuejs2

i have these components:

```
<template id="test-button-component">
    <div class="test-button__container">
        This is test button
        <button @click="clickButton">{{buttonTitle}}</button>
    </div>
</template>

<template id="test-button-component2">
    <div class="test-button__container">
         <button></button>
    </div>
</template>
```

I try to use the Vue's `:is` binding to do a component binding by name as follow:

```
<div :is='myComponentName' ></div>
```

every time the `myComponentName` changed to other component, the new component will replace the old component. The thing i need is, is there any way i can get the instance of the component so i can get the view model instance of the currently bound component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a [`ref` attribute](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) (for example `ref="custom"`) to the `<div>` tag for the dynamic component. And then reference the component instance via `this.$refs.custom`.

Here's a simple example where the data of the component gets logged whenever the value being bound to the `is` prop is changed:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return { 
      value: 'foo',
      children: {
        foo: { 
          name: 'foo',
          template: '<div>foo</div>',
          data() { 
            return { value: 1 };
          }
        },
        bar: {
          name: 'bar',
          template: '<div>bar</div>',
          data() { 
            return { value: 2 };
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    custom() {
      return this.children[this.value];
    }
  },
  watch: {
    custom() {
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        console.log(this.$refs.custom.$data)
      });
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="value">
    <option>foo</option>
    <option>bar</option>
  </select>
  <div :is="custom" ref="custom"></div>
</div>
```

Note that the `$data` for the component reference by `$refs.custom` is getting logged inside of a [`$nextTick` handler](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-nextTick). This is because the bound component won't update until the parent view has re-rendered.

Comment: i want to do something like ```counterFromComponent = componentVM.counter```, how can i access the properties or method i define under ```Vue.Component({
     data: function(){counter:123}
});``` like this?

Comment: In the example I posted, the `this.$refs.custom.$data` is the `data` properties object of the child component. So if it had `counter` property you could access it via `this.$refs.custom.$data.counter`.